# How to Convert empty string into NULL in HIVE Parquet table?

Tags: hive

I have a requirement to convert all blank values into NULL while loading and all of my target tables are parquet as per the requirement.
But I am unable to convert those values into NULL.

I am working on very large scale of data like 500gb or some tables are in TBs.
I have tried " 'serialization.null.format' = '' " but its not working.
And also i have tried case and if statement to convert those values in data laod phase. This method is working but it's taking too much time because of the data volume.
Is there any better solution using which I can achieve the conversion of blank into NULL?

Answer (score 0):

I think, case condition can help you in this regard.

`case when $column<>'' then $column else NULL`

If you are fetching this data from raw format say JSON, it will take more time than fetching from ORC files

Comment: I have tried it but its taking too much time to process because data sets which I am using is in TBs.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the next [link](http://boopathi.me/blog/enable-hive-metastore-null-empty-string/), carefully and it will work directly, without the case transformation.

Shortly: before you use "serialization.null.format", you need to setup an option on Cloudera.

Comment: Thanks much, I'll try it and let you know.